# How to display output from my Dictionary Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I want to create an extension that takes the selected text from the webpage, search about on a dictionary and return the definition. I think Im fine with the coding part, but I dont really understand how to display correctly my output.

My idea was to create a popup but I dont understand how to set the position of that popup, right now I was never able to move it away from right under the extension icon on Chrome.

Bonus:

1. I'm also trying to set a different opacity on the background, to better display only text of the output, without a particular box background, but changing the alpha value doesnt seem to affect anything.
2. Is it possible to open the popup with a single key instead of clicking the extension? I tried event listeners but they seem to be deaf.

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === 'searchDictionary') {
    var results = performDictionaryLookup(request.text);
    sendResponse({ results: results });
  }
});

function performDictionaryLookup(text) {
  var dictionaryData = loadDictionaryFromFile('dictionary.txt');
  var lowercaseText = text.toLowerCase();
  var results = findMatchingTerms(dictionaryData, lowercaseText);
  return results.length > 0 ? results : ['No definitions found for ' + text];
}

function loadDictionaryFromFile(filename) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', chrome.runtime.getURL(filename), false);
  xhr.send();
  var dictionaryContent = xhr.responseText;
  return JSON.parse(dictionaryContent);
}

function findMatchingTerms(dictionary, text) {
  var matchingTerms = [];
  for (const key in dictionary) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().includes(text)) {
      matchingTerms.push({ term: key, definition: dictionary[key] });
    }
  }
  return matchingTerms;
}
```

popup.js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'window.getSelection().toString();'
  }, function(selection) {
    var selectedText = selection[0].trim();
    console.log('Selected Text:', selectedText);

    if (selectedText !== '') {
      searchDictionary(selectedText);
    } else {
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'No text selected.';
    }
  });
});

function searchDictionary(text) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'searchDictionary', text: text }, function(response) {
    if (response && response.results) {
      console.log('Response:', response);

      var resultsContainer = document.getElementById('result');
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results

      if (response.results.length > 0) {
        response.results.forEach(function(result) {
          var resultElement = document.createElement('div');
          resultElement.innerText = result.definition;
          resultsContainer.appendChild(resultElement);
        });
      } else {
        resultsContainer.innerText = 'No definitions found for ' + text;
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Invalid or missing response:', response);
      document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Error fetching dictionary entry.';
    }
  });
}
```

popup.html

```
<!-- popup.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Dictionary Extension</title>
  <style>
    body {
      width: 200px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
      padding: 10px; /* Add padding for better spacing */
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); /* Set background color with transparency */
      border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Add a border */
      border-radius: 5px; /* Add rounded corners */
      font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif; /* Set font family */
      font-size: 9px; /* Set font size */
      color: #333; /* Set text color */
      margin: 0; /* Remove default margin for body */
    }

    p {
      margin: 0; /* Remove default margin for <p> */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Your popup content goes here -->
  <p id="result">&gt; *output*</p>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Dictionary Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Lookup selected text in a Python dictionary.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the `action` popup's position and backrgound are hardcoded. Instead of using it you can simply add a DOM element to the web page and [style it any way](/a/25100953) you want.